# Matrices AB, BA eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Take two matrices $A$ $n\times m$ and $B$ $m\times n$. They both have a nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$. How do you prove that the dimension of the eigenspaces of $AB$ and $BA$ corresponding to $\lambda$ are equal?

i.e., $\dim E_\lambda(AB) = \dim E_\lambda(BA)$.

Attempt: If you take $L$ independent eigenvectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ of $AB$, they get $Bv_1, \ldots, Bv_n$ eigenvectors in $BA$. This is apparently important in the proof, but I can't understand where to use this fact.
Please help.

Comment: The only answer on the duplicate hints towards showing that $\lambda\neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ iff of $BA$. It remains to see that the eigenspaces have the same dimension. What Martin Argerami's answer shows. Somehow, we would need to make that other answer a duplicate of this one as well to get the full answer...But I guess it is not possible or simply not the usage.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that your $Bv_1,\ldots,Bv_n$ are necessarily linearly independent. Because if
$$
c_1Bv_1+\cdots+c_nBv_n=0,
$$
then applying $A$ we get
$$
0=c_1ABv_1+\cdots+c_nABv_n=c_1\lambda v_1+\cdots+c_n\lambda v_n=\lambda(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n).
$$
As $\lambda\ne0$, you get that $Bv_1,\ldots,Bv_n$ are linearly independent.

So far we have shown that $\dim E_\lambda(AB)\leq\dim E_\lambda(BA)$. But of course now we can get the reverse inequality by starting with $BA$ instead of $AB$.

Comment: If a space has $n$ linearly independent vectors, then the space has at least dimension $n$. This is actually not far from the *definition* of dimension in a vector space: the dimension is the size of the smallest basis, which is necessarily linearly independent.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro but $v_1, ..., v_n$ are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors for $AB$. $Bv_1, ..., Bv_n$ are also $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors for $BA$. Why is there an inequality?

Comment: Because in the first case, it is *the* $n$ linearly independent $\lambda$-eigenvectors of $AB$ (so $E_\lambda(AB)$ has dimension $n$ by assumption), while in the second case, it is $n$ linearly independent vectors (which may not exhaust the space), so $E_\lambda(BA)$ has dimension $\ge n$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Thanks! I understand the problem now.